# How to plot closeness_centrality in a bar graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, bar-chart, networkx

I have been trying to plot closeness_centrality into a bar chart and I'm getting the error saying "cannot unpack non-iterable int object". Not sure if I can unpack the closeness_centrality like the way above. Please help with this. Thanks

```
import networkx as nx
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#draw complete bi-partite graph
plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
cbg= nx.complete_bipartite_graph(20,15)
nx.draw_networkx(cbg)
p = nx.closeness_centrality(cbg)        
for a,b in p:
    s.append(b)
plt.bar(cbg.nodes,s, align='center', alpha=1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This isn't enough code to be able to work out what's going wrong. You should try to create a [reprex]

Comment: updated the entire code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your have `s` undefined in the following code fragment:

```
for a,b in p:
    s.append(b)
```

But you do not need the fragment at all. Centralities are the values of the dictionary `p`:

```
plt.bar(cbg.nodes, p.values(), align='center', alpha=1)
```